# In Star Trek TOS, when was the first mention of a shuttlecraft, and when did the producers decide the Enterprise had shuttles?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

The first episode of *Star Trek*/TOS that used a shuttlecraft was *The Galileo Seven*, which included the full interior and exterior of the shuttle. That was more than halfway through the season (Episode S01E16). Earlier, in *The Enemy Within* (S01E05), there is no mention of the shuttle at all, even when it would have solved the problem of rescuing the men stranded on the planet in the extreme cold. (Or did I miss a mention of it there?) I've read a comment from Roddenberry about the transporter being created because they couldn't land a big ship on a planet every week, which indicates he wasn't even thinking of any kind of shuttle in the early part of the production process.

So a two part question:

1. Is there any documentation about when the concept of having a shuttle on the *Enterprise* was developed and was it part of the concept from the beginning of the show?
2. When was the shuttlecraft first mentioned in the series? Was it before *The Galileo 7*?

Comment: As I heard it, the shuttlecraft was in the original concept but the set for it hadn't been built yet.  The transporter was invented so they could visit planets in the first few episodes, and it just caught on.

Comment: Roddenberry noting the Enterprise is not designed to land has nothing to with shuttles.  Given that the Enterprise has always had a shuttlebay the absence of a shuttle in early stories where it would have been useful can be solely attributed to the out universe lack of a model and sets and a script that works fine without being nitpicked.

Comment: @lucasbachmann The Enterprise always had that space in the rear, but was it intended as a shuttle bay from the start? And if they had shuttles, why would Roddenberry be thinking of landing the full ship on a planet at all? Remember, when they finally did use the shuttle, we never saw it land or take off or doing anything but flying in space.

Comment: Prior to Star Trek science fiction had rockets or saucers doing the landing. See Buck Roger's, Rocketship X-M, Forbidden Planet.  And obviously JJ Abrams didn't get - the Enterprise is uniquely meant for Zero gravity.  It is not aerodynamic and it is held together by narrow sections.

Comment: @lucasbachmann I agree in many ways with your point about the Constitution Class being intended only for flight in space, but I think when you consider the stresses battle maneuvers and other things we saw (like breaking free of tractor beams or fighting one in, say, The Apple) show us that things like the nacelle struts can handle enormous stress. Still, there's a difference between a hull holding pressure IN than standing against outside pressure. (That also bothered me in Airport '77!)

Comment: Not that it's entirely relevant, but my understanding is that in the original concept the entire saucer section was meant to land every week. That's why the Enterprise is shaped the way it is - it's a flying saucer for planetary travel, coupled to a warp drive section that stays in orbit. The saucer separation concept was brought back for TNG, but even then it was so expensive it was hardly used at all.

Comment: @N.Virgo I don't think they ever planned on landing the saucer regularly. The saucer did have landing struts (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11606/1693) and in the Apple Kirk tells Scotty to do a saucer sep if necessary - it's treated like a last resort. I think I remember reading that in TOS, the saucer could not re-attach.

Comment: @Tango I'm trying to remember where I read this, but I understood the idea that the saucer would land regularly was part of the initial concept but was nixed pretty early on and never made it to screen. Presumably, that happened after the Enterprise model was designed but before any scripts were written, and hence the saucer and its landing legs were retconned as emergency measures rather than something that would be regularly used.

Comment: @Tango because I'm unsure about that I've asked [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/286120/was-the-tos-saucer-section-ever-intended-to-land-regularly) about it.

Comment: @N.Virgo Good! I'll be interested in the answers. From what I remember (which is likely mostly from The Making of... by Whitfield, I don't think there was talk of doing this with the saucer, but I could be way off on that.

Comment: @Tango - ... and the most annoying thing about script writers' ignorance is that they sometimes hit bullseye - in naval tradition, which ST apparently emulates to some extent - shuttle is a small boat used to move personnel, supplies (rarely) and communications (obviously age of sail) between ships. Tender or launch (though that last one is less a type, more a function description) would be the "shuttle" of today - tenders used to carry ppl, supplies (lots), landing parties and foraging parties and so on; while launch would be for carrying people (incl. VIPs and ship's CO).

Comment: see middle row far right image for the "hangar deck" on a near final draft design https://forgottentrek.com/the-original-series/designing-the-first-enterprise/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> …Before we go any further discussing the transporter either scientifically or dramatically, let’s see how this mess got started. Was the machine a part of the series from the beginning?
>
> Contrary to popular belief, it was not. The first series outline-dated March 1964 contained no mention of anything so fantastic. The problem of transit between the large ship and any surface was handled by the only obvious answer, a “small shuttle rocket.” There were no story springboards involving a machine which would destroy the characters’ concept of distance and transportation times.
> [image]

Van Treuren, Richard. "On Ship-to-Surface Transportation". *Best of Trek*. March 1980. p. 53-65.

According to Wikipedia. The 1964 original premise for Star Trek mentioned...

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttlecraft_(Star_Trek)

> Dated March 1964, the premise mentions a "small shuttle rocket".[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U74cA.png) The shuttle rocket was too expensive to build for the first episodes. For most of the series the transporter served to teleport characters on and off the ship.

The source was given as

Van Treuren, Richard. "On Ship-to-Surface Transportation". *Best of Trek*. March 1980. p. 53-65.

> *Richard G. Van Treuren Rich Van Treuren's articles on the Star Trek miniatures in The Best of Trek #1 proved to be among the most popular in that collection. So armed with dozens of laudatory letters, we prevailed upon Rich to once more turn his writing attentions to Star Trek. His first few submissions to us were a series of excellent photo oriented articles, which, sadly, we are not able to include in this collection. However, just before our deadline for this book, Rich wrote and informed us he had "a little something on the transporter" that was mostly text, and might be suitable for inclusion. The "little something" turned out to be the most detailed and entertaining article on the
> transporter we have ever seen! We believe you will think so.*
>
> It was September 1964. The new, unique television show was taking shape. Its science-fictional spaceship, created by artists/ aviators, had been whittled out in model form. The pi- lot film story had been chosen. Even though the first-script draft was carefully prepared by an experienced entertainer with wide aviation experience, the opinion of an aerospace professional was solicited. The physicist took exception to
> only one major point-something called the "transporter." "What kind of fun is that?" he wrote. "Where is the suspense?" The scientist, of course, was H. P. Lynn; he was offering criticism to creator Gene Roddenberry. The story was made public in *The Making of Star Trek*. Here we had the most perfectly credible science-fiction space project ever attempted for television. (Admittedly, that is not saying very much.) Every facet had been either created or supervised by knowledgeable types. The pilot script was a…

[image]

Comment: Nice find--to address question #2 (not worth posting as a separate answer), assuming Tango was asking about [production order](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls058233287/) rather than airdate order, I did keyword searches on the [chakoteya.net](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/episodes.htm) transcripts for the 13 episodes before "Galileo 7", the prior episode "Conscience of a King" had Kirk giving Lenore a tour and saying "That's the flight deck down there with the shuttle craft". In "The Corbonite Maneuver" McCoy also asks if he is a doctor or a "moon shuttle conductor" but that doesn't count...

Comment: The Enemy Within 1x05 is probably the most notorious with fans as a shuttle would presumably have solved the freezing Sulu vs malfunctioning transporter problem.  Obviously just because we don't know the in-universe reason doesn't mean one can't be invented to preserve continuity.

Comment: @lucasbachmann One issue about The Enemy Within is that there wasn't even a throw-away line, "Normally we'd use the shuttlecraft, but we can't because..." and add any kind of excuse like repairs, heavy radiation out there, some odd atmospheric layer, and so on. That there wasn't even an excuse given makes it seem like it wasn't even a consideration.

Comment: Great answer overall, but the opening quotation is rather confusing without context — am I understanding right that “the machine” refers to the transporter, not the shuttlecraft?

Comment: Yes looking at the whole page. The machinre referred to is the transporter.

Comment: I added a larger photo of more of the page and wrote the beginning of the quote so it is clear the machine being referred to is the transporter. Thank you @PLl

Comment: additional info on H.P. Lynn http://trekplace.com/harveyplynnjr.html

Comment: I can't cite any source for this, but as I understand it, one early concept was for the whole ship to land. Because the effects work for this was estimated to be a prohibitive production cost, the transporter was conceived, and the ship was re-imagined to be incapable of landing on a planet. That might have been before the Enterprise design was realized in any detail. This leaves the shuttlecraft as almost an afterthought, although it was apparently baked into the concept by the time the first episodes were being shot, which was well under way before the shuttlecraft prop was delivered.

Answer (score 12):

The very first mention of a shuttle *of any sort* is from [TOS: The Corbomite Maneuver](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/3.htm) (airdate 10 Nov, 1966). In this instance, a *moon* shuttle.

> **KIRK:** I'll be right up. You could see the alarm lights flashing from there, McCoy. Why didn't you tell me?
>
> **MCCOY:** Finally finished a physical on you, didn't I. (Kirk leaves) What am I, a doctor or **a moon shuttle conductor**? If I jumped every time a light came on around here, I'd end up talking to myself.

The first example of *a Federation facility* possessing shuttlecraft is from [TOS: The Menagerie](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/16.htm) (airdate 17 Nov, 1966), in this case a Starbase Shuttle.

> **MENDEZ:** ***Starbase Shuttlecraft one** to Enterprise. Come in, please. Enterprise, Commodore Mendez and Captain Kirk. If you read me, you are ordered to reply. Repeating it on all emergency frequencies, Jim.*

The very first mention of the Enterprise having its own shuttles is from is [TOS: The Conscience of the King](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/13.htm) (airdate 8 Dec, 1966)

> **KIRK:** *This is the observation deck. That's the flight deck down there **with the shuttle craft.***

And the first time we see a *named* shuttlecraft aboard the Enterprise is, as you say, from the titular [TOS: The Galileo Seven](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/14.htm) (airdate 5 Jan, 1967).

> **KIRK:** *Captain to shuttlecraft Galileo. Stand by, Mister Spock.*

Comment: I that reference in The Corbomite Maneuver is a general reference, so you're right that it's not to a shuttlecraft.

Comment: @Tango - Yes. All he says is that there's a moon shuttle. We don't know if it's a literal [Shuttlecraft](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shuttlecraft) or if he means a shuttle as in ['shuttle bus'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_bus) (e.g. a regular short transit from a to b)

Answer (score 2):

The Enterprise had a "hangar deck" or "flight deck" in early drafts of the Constitution class design by Matt Jeffries.  So by implication, shuttlecraft or equivalent small ships were always part of the plan.  (Though I'd speculate small visiting alien ships could visit too like Babylon 5 had.)

(I just also noticed Matt Jeffries' registry scheme would have made the future Motion Picture refit be 1701A as a structure modification - rather than the honorary designation.)

From website **"Forgotten Trek: Designing the First Enterprise"**

https://forgottentrek.com/the-original-series/designing-the-first-enterprise/

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wish there were dates on these sketches, since there's the story that the original Enterprise design was upside down to what we know and when it came time to hang the model for display, it was hung upside down and well received, so they stuck with the upside-down version, which is what we have now. One reason I doubt this is the design of the shuttle hanger and the curve up under it - that wouldn't really work as a hanger with a landing deck if  the ship were upside down.

Comment: @Tango I suspect the upside-down stuff is related to some of the drafts with the sphere hull and later became the basis of the Daedalus class model in DS9/TNG for a pre-Constitution class.