# Other starships that can undergo saucer separation?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

I know that the *Enterprise-D* was capable of saucer separation (this was displayed in several episodes including *The Best of Both Worlds*, *Encounter at Farpoint* and in the film *Generations*).  I also know the *Prometheus* class was capable of saucer separation (albeit in the form of 'multi-vector assault mode').  And according to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5247/could-the-original-or-other-enterprises-saucers-separate), it seems the good old Constitution class was capable of saucer separation.  My question is: **what other starships (if any) were capable of saucer-separation?**  Note I would like to include non-Federation ships as well and would like to stick to canon references.

Comment: The only one ever shown on-screen was the Enterprise-D. That would make it the only canon reference.

Comment: @BBlake that's correct but I don't mind off screen references as well

Comment: There was one that I can't remember the name of. It was shown in Voyager's "Message In A Bottle".

Comment: @NateWatson - The would be the USS Prometheus; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_in_a_Bottle_%28Star_Trek:_Voyager%29

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [Memory Alpha article](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Saucer_separation) suggests that the following ships / classes are also capable of seperation although it is never shown directly in a movie or episode:

- Enterprise-A / Constitution class (only as last resort)
- Enterprise-B / Excelsior class
- Enterprise-C / Ambassador class
- Enterprise-E / Sovereign class

Comment: The original Constitution class Enterprises (1701 & 1701A) also had this capability. I had a set of the original technical blueprints set released in the 1970's that clearly indicated the saucer section could detach to be used "as a lifeboat"

Comment: If you could add that the Constitution refit could also undergo this that would be great thanks

Answer (score 8):

The Abrams continuity shows the rebooted 1701 saucer separation. It's done here to allow the saucer to use its own power, after the neck was destroyed. As seen in *Star Trek: Beyond* (happens towards the end of the clip)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Technical Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_Technical_Manual), even the Defiant Class possesses this ability, even in a slightly different form (instead of *saucer hull* it is probably better to speak of *primary* and *secondary hull* here).

[image]

> The notched forward hull containing the vessel's navigational deflector and main sensors was a **detachable single-use last-resort missile**. This missile was equipped with a small impulse engine and a magazine with six torpedo warheads. These torpedo warheads were part of the ship's auto-destruct system and under more normal circumstances could be fired from the forward launcher. Any torpedo warheads left in the magazine would become the missile's warhead upon the missile's separation from the rest of the ship. If no torpedo warheads remained, then the missile would have to rely on kinetic energy alone. The ship would be unable to travel at high warp speeds without the missile since the latter contained the ship's navigational deflector.
>   <sub>Quote from [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Defiant_class#Warhead)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The classes where it's been seen
The Enterprise-d [Galaxy-class]
Prometheus class (multiple units)
Constitution class (Alternate reality)

Sketches produced by John Eaves; chief designer for the TNG movies; sketches of the early Enterprise E during "First Contact", the Sovereign class vessel  appeared capable of doing that.
[image]

Comment: Where were these sketches published?

Answer (score -1):

I believe in TOS, the planet with BAL that was pulling /heat rays on the Enterprise; Kirk tells Scotty something to the statement of "jettison the nacelles and escape with the main section"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is noted in the question (as explicitly described in the linked question); the question was if there are any _other_ ships that have a similar mode.